# how to re-write string in jquery to avoid accessing the dom again, and use jquery selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I am trying to re-write some jquery so that uses a selector I had previously created, so that it doesn't need to access the DOM again. The selector I had created already access the DOM once, and I want to use its contents in a string literal in a function.

My current code is the following:

```
$(this.$content[$(`.nav a[href$="${window.location.hash}"]`).parent().index()]).show();
```

which works just fine, but ".nav a" is accessing the DOM, which I do not want in this instance. I want to use this.$navigation, which I had created before and already has the information from the DOM. I tried writing it as

```
$(this.$content[$(`this.$navigation.find('a')[href$="${window.location.hash}"]`).parent().index()]).show();
```

where this.navigation = $("#main-nav"), the parent of the .nav elements, but it does not work in this way.

Any suggestions on how I might approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner jQuery object should be moved outside of the string literal, and the attribute selector needs to be placed inside the `find()` call.

```
$(this.$content[$(this.$navigation).find(`a[href$="${window.location.hash}"]`).parent().index()]).show();
```

In addition, I would assume from the naming convention that `$navigation` already holds a jQuery object so does not need to be wrapped again. As such, this should work:

```
$(this.$content[this.$navigation.find(`a[href$="${window.location.hash}"]`).parent().index()]).show();
```